# how to hide a nav button declare in the index page?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I declare a nav button in index page and it shown all the page But  I want remove from my home page. How can I remove that button in that specific pages

Comment: Create that nav in separate view and add and remove that view

Answer (score 1):

make $rootScope array of pages where you don't want to show the button. Then use ng-if in button tag to show n hide the button

```
<button ng-if="root.pageIgnore.indexOf($route.current.name) === -1">Shy Button</Button>
```